# Efficiently vectorize an element-wise operation in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

I have an nx4 matrix `A` representing n spheres, and an mx3 matrix `B` representing m points. I need to test whether these m points are inside any of the spheres. I can do this using a `for` loop, but with large `n` and `m` this method is very inefficient. How can I vectorize this operation? My current method is

```
A = [0.8622    1.1594    0.7457    0.6925;
     1.4325    0.2559    0.0520    0.4687;
     1.8465    0.3979    0.2850    0.4259;
     1.4387    0.8713    1.6585    0.4616;
     0.2383    1.5208    0.5415    0.9417;
     1.6812    0.2045    0.1290    0.1972];

B = [0.5689    0.9696    0.8196;
     0.5211    0.4462    0.6254;
     0.9000    0.4894    0.2202;
     0.4192    0.9229    0.4639];

for i=1:size(B,1)

    mask = vecnorm(A(:, 1:3) - B(i,:), 2, 2) < A(:, 4);

    if sum(mask) > 0
        C(i) = true;
    else
        C(i) = false;
    end %if

end %for
```

I tested the method suggested by @LuisMendo, and it seems it only speeds up the calculation for quite small `m` and `n`, but for large `m` and `n`, say, around 10000 for my problem, the improvement is very limited. But @NickyMattsson gave me some hint. Because logical operation in matlab is faster than `vecnorm`, I first use a rough check to find the spheres near the point, and then do a fine check:

```
A = [0.8622    1.1594    0.7457    0.6925;
     1.4325    0.2559    0.0520    0.4687;
     1.8465    0.3979    0.2850    0.4259;
     1.4387    0.8713    1.6585    0.4616;
     0.2383    1.5208    0.5415    0.9417;
     1.6812    0.2045    0.1290    0.1972];

B = [0.5689    0.9696    0.8196;
     0.5211    0.4462    0.6254;
     0.9000    0.4894    0.2202;
     0.4192    0.9229    0.4639];

ids = 1:size(A, 1);

for i=1:size(B,1)

    % first a rough check
    xbound = abs(A(:, 1) - B(i, 1)) < A(:, 4);
    ybound = abs(A(:, 2) - B(i, 2)) < A(:, 4);
    zbound = abs(A(:, 3) - B(i, 3)) < A(:, 4);
    nears = ids(xbound & ybound & zbound);
    if isempty(nears)
        C(i) = false;
    else 
        % then a fine check
        mask = vecnorm(A(nears, 1:3) - B(i,:), 2, 2) < A(nears, 4);

        if sum(mask) > 0
            C(i) = true;
        else
            C(i) = false;
        end 
    end

end
```

This may reduce the time to 1/2 or 1/3, which is acceptable, and if I divide `m` and `n` into batches it may be even faster without too heavy memory burden. @CrisLuengo mentioned the R*-tree method, but it seems that the implementation is quite complicated XD

Comment: What Matlab version?

Comment: @LuisMendo 2018a

Comment: I'm not convinced that vectorizing this will make it faster. The correct approach is to use an R*-tree to find points that are within each circle. That will reduce the operation from O(mn) to O(n log m) (or something of similarly lower complexity).

Comment: @CrisLuengo could you elaborate that a little bit?

Comment: [Wikipedia R*tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/R*_tree) — It is a data structure that makes it cheap to find points within a box. You can find all points in the bounding box of one circle, then test each one of those with Euclidean distance to the center to find the ones that are inside the circle. Repeat for each circle. This prevents computing Euclidean distances between each point and each center. Not sure if there is an implementation of R-trees in MATLAB, so this might be a lot of computing. But if speed is important, that would be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

This uses [implicit expansion](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/) to compute all distances between points and sphere centers, and then to compare those with the sphere radii:

```
C = any(vecnorm(permute(B, [1 3 2]) - permute(A(:,1:3), [3 1 2]), 2, 3) < A(:,4).', 2);
```

This is probably faster than the loop approach, but also more memory-intensive, because an intermediate `m`×`n`×`3` array is computed.

Comment: Just to add to Luis' answer, if the `m x n x 3` matrix is too large, you simply do it in batches. i.e. instead of checking all `m` points at once, only check `mhat` where `mhat` is smaller than `m` such that the `mhat x n x 3` fits in the memory. Then you loop over these batches.